# My thermostat is off but the blower on my central air unit is randomly cycling on and off

Tags: hvac

Earlier today with my thermostat on "cool" and the fan on "auto," my blower came on, it's only 72 degrees and I thought the thermostat had gotten turned down and the a/c had kicked on. I checked and the thermostat was well above 72 and the outside unit was not running, only the fan. I turned the thermostat completely off but the fan remained on. It ran about 2 minutes then shut off by itself. About 10 minutes later it did it again, ran for a couple minutes then shut off with the thermostat still set on "off". About 10 minutes later I'd did it again so I removed the thermostat and it continued running. It has done this several times now. I'm no HVAC expert so any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Get your volt meter and check the fan relay control circuit for intermittent closing and opening. Also check the fan relay to see if the contacts are the problem, opening and closing on their own.